# Google chrome not remembering password

Tags: google-chrome

I'll have to login to http://192.168.1.1/ each session to access internet.

I want chrome to store this password but it's not  happening.

However, in other sites (like fb,gmail) chrome is able to store the passwords.

How can i make it store passwords for this IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to make Google Chrome offer to save (prompt) password for a particular site (for e.g abcd.com) and Auto-login the site with the credentials thus saved.
-> Go to the given URL 'abcd.com'
-> Right-click Page Info and disable 'JavaScript'
-> Reload the page.
-> Enter the credentials (uid,pwd)
-> A prompt appears to save password.
-> Click on Save password.
-> Auto-Login Extension bubble appears on this page.

At this point it is important because the extension 'Auto-Login' (like many other extensions) require
JavaScript to be enabled.
-> Re-enable the JavaScript for this page and reload the page.
-> Now Click on the 'Auto-Login' bubble for remembering automatically logging into the site hereafter!

Comment: It solved my problem